# Avoiding nested using blocks when outer is used only to construct inner

Tags: c#, using, idisposable

Often, the `IDisposable` object of a `using` block is itself constructed from another `IDisposable` object, e.g.

```
using (FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
using (MyObject obj = new MyObject(stream))
{
  // do something with obj
}
```

Unfortunately the code above keeps the file stream open until the `MyObject` object is disposed.

To dispose of the file stream as soon as the `MyObject` constructor has completed, I could instead write:

```
MyObject CreateMyObject(string path)
{
  using (FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
  {
    return new MyObject(stream);
  }
}

using (MyObject obj = CreateMyObject(path))
{
  // do something with obj
}
```

But I don't like the verbosity of this solution. I tried replacing `CreateMyObject()` with a lambda but I failed to find a legal syntax. Is there a way to do this without calling a custom creator function?

---

Edit: Bearing in mind some of the comments, I should point out that I'm trying to avoid `try`...`finally` - kind of the main reason for a `using` block in the first place.

Additional clarification: The MyObject object is constructed from information in the stream - i.e. its constructor reads the content of the stream in its entirity. No other method in MyObject references the stream. The content of the stream could come from anywhere - a file, a resource, an Internet socket, etc.

Comment: you dont need a `using` block at all, you could just create the stream, pass to `MyObject`, then call `stream.Dispose()`. Or course, you'll need to wrap this in a `try catch`

Comment: What would be the point of writing it like that? Why do you only need the stream in the constructor?

Comment: You're aware that `obj = ...; using (obj) { .. }` is a thing, right? You are not required to initialize the variable and wrap it in one single block. If you're concerned about `obj` possibly not being disposed when an exception occurs, just use `try .. finally` yourself instead of `using`.

Comment: Why is the stream being passed to the constructor?

Comment: If you don't need the stream for the whole time, why it needs to be passed as constructor argument? Maybe the constructor should not take the stream but what you want to read with it. Or it could at take the file-path and create and use it there. Is `MyObject` supposed to be the reader-class or just the class that holds the informations which you want to read? It should not be used for both because that are two separate concerns.

Comment: @IanGoldby perhaps you should just tell us why its being passed in the constructor.  I have never in my life passed a stream to a constructor, nor have I seen any library doing that.  It seems like a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could invoke some magic like so:

```
TResult CreateUsingDisposable<TDisposable, TResult>(TDisposable disposable, Func<TDisposable, TResult> getResult)
  where TDisposable : IDisposable
{
  using (disposable)
  {
    return getResult(disposable);
  }
}

using (var obj = CreateUsingDisposable(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open), stream => new MyObject(stream)))
{
}
```

But why? There's a super easy to read no-nonsense way of doing that:

```
  MyObject obj;
  using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
  {
    obj = new MyObject(stream);
  }
  using (obj)
  {

  }
```

Comment: Wouldnt the stream be disposed by the time you get to `using(obj)`?

Comment: @maccettura That's the point. You _want_ the stream closed as soon as the `MyObject` constructor has completed.

Comment: Forget the 'magic'. The second bit of code is exactly what I was flailing so hopelessly around for. Thanks. (Can I suggest you edit the 1st solution out of your answer?)

Comment: @IanGoldby I don’t think he should.  He’s making a very good point that the best way is the more readable way.   The other solutions here and elsewhere on this page are arguably nothing more than an excercise in cleverness at the expense of readability

Comment: @MickyD You mean keep the 'clever' but less clear solution as a counterpoint to the no-nonsense good solution? Not sure I agree - a clear and simple solution stands on its own merit.

Comment: @IanGoldby well I think we're talking about the same thing

Answer (score 1):

While I don't see a way to avoid the creator function, you can make it generic enough to define once and use for any class:

```
static T WithStream<T>(string path, Func<FileStream, T> getter)
{
  using (FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
  {
    return getter(stream);
  }
}

class MyObject : IDisposable
{
    public MyObject (Stream stream){ /* Work with stream */}
    public void Dispose(){}

}
static void Main()
{

    using (MyObject obj = WithStream("path", fs => new MyObject(fs)))
    {
      // do something with obj
    }
}
```